# how to print an array from an object in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

```
const api = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'https://iotserver-arha83.herokuapp.com/api/customers/'
})
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    courses:[]
  }
  constructor(){
    super();
    api.get('/').then(res =>{
      this.setState({courses: res.data})
    })
  }
  render(){return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <table>
        <tr><td>pk</td>{this.state.courses.map(course=><td>{course.pk}</td>)}</tr>
        <tr><td>title</td>{this.state.courses.map(course=><td>{course.title}</td>)}</tr>
        <tr><td>gateway</td>{this.state.courses.map(course=><td>{course.gateway}</td>)}</tr>
        </table>     
      </header>
    </div>
  );}
}
export default App;
```

```
[
    {
        "pk": 1, 
        "title": "first", 
        "gateways": [1]
    }, {
        "pk": 2, 
        "title": "second", 
        "gateways": [2]
    }, {
        "pk": 5, 
        "title": "test", 
        "gateways": []
    }, {
        "pk": 6, 
        "title": "test", 
        "gateways": []
    }
]
```

this is my code and I want to print every item on my website
but I can't print gateways because it's an array
I tried to change the gateway into string so it might be printed but didn't work
any ideas...?
note: this code should print every thing on the upper list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to iterate over the array only once using the `map()` method and render a `tr` for each element.

```js
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>pk</th>
    <th>title</th>
    <th>gateway</th>
  </tr>
  {courses.map((course) => (
    <tr key={course.pk}>
      <td>{course.pk}</td>
      <td>{course.title}</td>
      <td>{course.gateways.join(",")}</td>
    </tr>
  ))}
</table>
```

Property `gateways` is also an array which you can `map` too, however since you only want to render values you can use `join(",")` method instead.

[image: Edit zealous-panini-kfw4u]

***On a side note, it's better to start using functional components.***